# how to authenticate user login using javamail api in android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

is there a wayn to just authenticate the email address and password of a user using javamail api in android without sending them an email..so far this is my code which doesn't seem to solve anything..

```
btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


                  Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
                  private PasswordAuthentication authentication;
                  {
                  authentication = new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
                  if(authentication != null){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "incorrect Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                  }
                  }
                  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                  return authentication;
                  }
                  };
```

or anyone with a better solution to this,i'm eager to hear,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to the server and then disconnect without doing anything.  See the Store.connect and Transport.connect methods.